# How to send data to Flask webpage from another module

Tags: python, flask

I am trying to post data on flask that I get as a return from another module that gets data from a webpage and renders them as json. I am using flask and I render an html template for the home page. What I am trying to understand is the how posting or getting data from the "backend" to the "frontend" works. My setup currently is stateless.

Currently I am making a request to a redhat webpage and getting a json as a response. I would like to get some parts of that json and post them into the webpage. Things seems to work fine when I "print" the data outside the class but I cannot figure out how to import them in the webserver application if that makes sense.

```
class Application:

    app = Flask(__name__, template_folder='frontend/templates')

    @app.route("/")
    @app.route("/home")

    def home():
        return render_template("home.html")

    @app.route("/home", methods=['POST'])
    def get_response_data():
        redhat = CVE("CVE-xxx-xxxx")
        result = redhat.get_cve_json()['cve_id']
        return render_template('home.html', result=result)

    if __name__ == "__main__":
        app.run(debug=True)
```

```
{% block content %}

    </body>
        <form action="{{ result }} method=post">
    </div>
    </html>

    {% endblock %}
```

I have also tried to render the html page as such but I doubt this is the issue

```
    </body>
        <h2>{{ result }}</h2>
    </div>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found what the mistake was

I had this before the code mentioned above and it was breaking it.

```
    @app.route("/home)

    def home():
        return render_template("home.html")
```